# A family of open bounded intervals of $\mathbf{Q}$ whose union is $\mathbf{Q}$

Tags: general-topology, order-theory

> Let $E$ be a set and $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ a family of sets such that
> $E\subset\bigcup_{i\in I}X_i$. Then $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ is called a
> covering of $E$.

Is there a family of open, bounded  intervals of $\mathbf{Q}$ (i.e. intervals of the form $]x,y[$ s.t. $x,y\in\mathbf{Q}$) that covers $\mathbf{Q}$?

**Edit:**

Is there a family of open, bounded  intervals of $\mathbf{Q}$ (i.e. intervals of the form $]x,y[$ s.t. $x,y\in\mathbf{Q}$) whose union equals $\mathbf{Q}$?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: What about $\mathopen]-n,n\mathclose[$? By the way, the notation is terrible.

Comment: I guess the question is poorly expressed. I want to find a family of open bounded intervals of $\mathbf{Q}$ whose union equals $\mathbf{Q}$.

Comment: @ElliotG I am don't know where to begin. Would you mind sparing a hint?

Comment: If you mean that $\mathopen]x,y\mathclose[=\{z\in\mathbf{Q}:x<z<y\}$, then there is obviously no difference between using $\subset$ or $=$.

Comment: If you are looking for a collection of open intervals in $\Bbb R$ whose union is $\Bbb Q$, this is impossible, since every nonempty open interval contains an irrational number.

Comment: @egreg Yes that's what I meant. Given $x=a/b$ with $a\in\mathbf{Z}$ and $b>0$, how can I find $n\in\mathbf{N}$ such that $-n<a/b<n$?

Comment: @ElliotG The intervals are supposed to be in $\mathbf{Q}$.

Comment: Then take egreg's answer: the union of $]-n,n[$ is $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @egreg I suppose for $x=a/b$ $a\in\mathbf{Z}$ and $b>0$. I can always take $n$ to be $\max\{a,b\}$, right?

Comment: What is $x$? You are looking for a collection of bounded open intervals in $\Bbb Q$ whose union is $\Bbb Q$. The set of $]-n,n[$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$ is such a collection.

Comment: @egreg I understand that. The point is that given $x\in\mathbf{Q}$, I have to find $n\in\mathbf{N}$ such that $x\in(-n,n)$. I have to propose a candidate for such an $n$ in order to prove that the family of intervals $(-n,n)$ is what we're looking for. If $x\in\mathbf{Q}$, then $x=a/b$ for some $a\in\mathbf{Z}$ and $b>0$. I propose to take $n:=\max\{a,b\}$. That is all I meant. Anyways, thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry the above comment was meant for @ElliotG.

Comment: I see; you might just take $n=|a|$, since $|a/b|=|a|/|b|\le |a|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\Bbb Q$ is countable, take an enumeration of $\Bbb Q$ say $\{q_1,q_2,\dots,q_n,\dots\}$ .

Now take your $X_n=]q_n-\frac{1}{2^n},q_n+\frac{1}{2^n}[$

Comment : There were lot of examples of coverings provided in the comments but I decided to give this rather 'fancy' covering, because the OP is trying to learn and he/she should familarize himself/herself with this, as it will be very useful while doing Measure Theory in future.

Answer (score 1):

You have many choices. The simplest one is to take the intervals $\mathopen]-n,n\mathclose[$ (I use your notation even though I find it terrible), for $n$ running through the positive integer.

How do you show that every rational number belongs to such an interval? It is not restrictive to show it for $a/b$, with $a,b>0$. Then take $n=2a$; can you prove that $2a>a/b$? Hint: this is equivalent to $2ab>a$.

Comment: Okay, thank you.